# Spring Tool Suite Dashboard error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

My Spring source tool dashboard is giving me an error and doesn't display.

> Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".

I've searched this problem and cant find a solution. Anyone else experienced this and found a fix?

Comment: There might be more info in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory.

Comment: any one provide solution I am also facing with this issue..

Answer (score 0):

My problem is the same with you. But I got this error on Linux(ubuntu 12.04). But solved now. Because of the type of JDK. In Linux, we have to easily installed openjdk. OpenJDK is not supporting the JavaFX features used in the Spring Tools Suite Plugin. So, I have to change the oracle JDK and STS Dashboard was ok now.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Ubuntu 14.10. Eclipse 4.4.1, STS 3.6...

I installed openjfx. That resolved the issue for me.